# Microsoft Exchange 2013 - remove-mailboxpermission - an inherited access control entery has been specified

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, shared-mailbox

We have been using Exchange 2013 CU22 on Server 2012 R2.

I run this:

```
Remove-MailboxPermission "SharedMailbox" -User "User" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

I get this:

```
WARNING: An inherited access control entry has been specified: [Rights: CreateChild, Delete, ReadControl, WriteDacl, WriteOwner, ControlType: Allow]  and was ignored on o
bject "CN=SharedMailbox,DC=contoso,DC=com".
```

Get-MailboxPermission "SharedMailbox"

Result :

```
Identity             User                 AccessRights         IsInherited Deny 
--------             ----                 ------------         ----------- ---- 
contoso.com/... Contoso\User              {FullAccess}         False       True
```

Get-MailboxDatabase SharedDB | Get-ADPermission

Result :

```
Identity             User                 Deny  Inherited
--------             ----                 ----  ---------
SharedMailbox         Contoso\User      True  True
SharedMailbox         Contoso\User      False  True
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Blind

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps mentioned in this article to [Remove Exchange Inherited permissions to Mailboxes](https://pariswells.com/blog/tag/an-inherited-access-control-entry-has-been-specified). The permission can be added at multiple levels so it’s aways a diagnostic trail to where this was added. Go through each of those mentioned and if IsInherited is set to False you’ve found out where it’s being applied from.

Comment: Hi, is there any updates with your issue?